# I wanted to store jquery value alnog with form child element value after clicking on Submit button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to build a 5 star rating system. All code is working good, but when i am trying to store the rating value selected by the user along with the form elements which will have text area and text box i didnot get able to store them in database.

---

```
Here is my code
```

---

```
 star_rating.php

 <html>
   <head>
     <title>Testing</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="rating_style.css"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

            var clicked_val = 0;

        $("#1_star").hover(function() {
            $("#1_star").attr('src','clor.png');
            $("#2_star").attr('src','sta.png');
            $("#3_star").attr('src','sta.png');
            $("#4_star").attr('src','sta.png');
            $("#5_star").attr('src','sta.png');
        });

        $('#1_star').click(function() {
            clicked_val = 1;

        });

        $("#2_star").hover(function() {
            $("#1_star").attr('src','clor.png');
            $("#2_star").attr('src','clor.png');
            $("#3_star").attr('src','sta.png');
            $("#4_star").attr('src','sta.png');
            $("#5_star").attr('src','sta.png');
        });

        $('#2_star').click(function() {
            clicked_val = 2;

        });

        $("#3_star").hover(function() {
            $("#1_star").attr('src','clor.png');
            $("#2_star").attr('src','clor.png');
            $("#3_star").attr('src','clor.png');
            $("#4_star").attr('src','sta.png');
            $("#5_star").attr('src','sta.png');
        });

        $('#3_star').click(function() {
            clicked_val = 3;

        });

        $("#4_star").hover(function() {
            $("#1_star").attr('src','clor.png');
            $("#2_star").attr('src','clor.png');
            $("#3_star").attr('src','clor.png');
            $("#4_star").attr('src','clor.png');
            $("#5_star").attr('src','sta.png');

        });

        $('#4_star').click(function() {
            clicked_val = 4;

        });

        $("#5_star").hover(function() {
            $("#1_star").attr('src','clor.png');
            $("#2_star").attr('src','clor.png');
            $("#3_star").attr('src','clor.png');
            $("#4_star").attr('src','clor.png');
            $("#5_star").attr('src','clor.png');
        });

        $('#5_star').click(function() {
            clicked_val = 5;
        });
        $('.rating-star').mouseout(function() {
            if(clicked_val === 0 || clicked_val > 5)
            {
                $("#1_star").attr('src','sta.png');
                $("#2_star").attr('src','sta.png');
                $("#3_star").attr('src','sta.png');
                $("#4_star").attr('src','sta.png');
                $("#5_star").attr('src','sta.png');
            }


            else if (clicked_val === 1) 
            {
                $("#1_star").attr('src','clor.png');
                $("#2_star").attr('src','sta.png');
                $("#3_star").attr('src','sta.png');
                $("#4_star").attr('src','sta.png');
                $("#5_star").attr('src','sta.png');
            }

            else if (clicked_val === 2) 
            {
                $("#1_star").attr('src','clor.png');
                $("#2_star").attr('src','clor.png');
                $("#3_star").attr('src','sta.png');
                $("#4_star").attr('src','sta.png');
                $("#5_star").attr('src','sta.png'); 
            }

            else if (clicked_val === 3) 
            {
                $("#1_star").attr('src','clor.png');
                $("#2_star").attr('src','clor.png');
                $("#3_star").attr('src','clor.png');
                $("#4_star").attr('src','sta.png');
                $("#5_star").attr('src','sta.png');
            }

            else if (clicked_val === 4) 
            {
                $("#1_star").attr('src','clor.png');
                $("#2_star").attr('src','clor.png');
                $("#3_star").attr('src','clor.png');
                $("#4_star").attr('src','clor.png');
                $("#5_star").attr('src','sta.png'); 
            }

            else if (clicked_val === 5) 
            {
                $("#1_star").attr('src','clor.png');
                $("#2_star").attr('src','clor.png');
                $("#3_star").attr('src','clor.png');
                $("#4_star").attr('src','clor.png');
                $("#5_star").attr('src','clor.png');    
            }
        });

        $('#rate_this').click(function() {

            if(clicked_val === 0 || clicked_val > 5)
            {
                $('#response').html('Please give a rating');
            }
            else
            {                                                       

                $.ajax({

                    type: "POST",
                    cache: false,
                    url:'show.php',
                    data:'clicked_val='+clicked_val,
                    success: function(response)
                    {
                        $('#response').html(response);
                    }
                });
            }
        });


     });
    </script>

    </head>
   <body>
      <center>
         <div class="rating-container">
            <div class="rating-star">
               <img src="sta.png" width="50" id="1_star" />
               <img src="sta.png" width="50" id="2_star" />
               <img src="sta.png" width="50" id="3_star" />
               <img src="sta.png" width="50" id="4_star" />
               <img src="sta.png" width="50" id="5_star" />
            </div>
            <form method="post" id="rate_this">
               <input type="text" name="user_name"/>
               <input type="submit" value="submit" name="rating" id="submit_rating">
          </form>
           <div id="response"></div>
        </div>

     </center>
    </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: you are facing trouble saving them in database, or posting the value to php function, if database, please put your php code. your question is a bit unclear.

Comment: i am able to pass the rating vale to my second php code but i wanted to save it in db along with form elements.

Comment: so where you are trying to put them in db ? do you have any php code ?

Comment: @Neeraj then post all the from element using ajax not just the ratings.